# How to add one list of object to another

Tags: java, list, object

This is my code

I have eventBO list and eventReminderBo list... i need to add eventReminderDaysBOs to eventBOs...Because,i need to return only the eventBOs....

```
public List<EventBO> getAllEventsFromUser(UserBO userBO) throws UserServiceException {
        try {
            List<EventBO> eventBOs = new ArrayList<>();
            List<EventReminderDaysBO> eventReminderDaysBOs =new ArrayList<>();
            UserDO userDO = mapper.mapUserBOToDO(userBO, new UserDO());
            List<EventDO> eventDOs = eventDAOImpl.getAllEventsFromUser(userDO);
            for (EventDO eventDo : eventDOs) {
                EventBO eventBO = mapper.mapEventDOToBO(eventDo, new EventBO());
                eventBOs.add(eventBO);
                List<EventReminderDaysDO> eventReminderDaysDOs = eventDAOImpl.getAllEventsReminderDays(eventBO.getEventId());
                eventReminderDaysBOs = mapper.mapEventReminderDaysDOToBO( eventReminderDaysDOs, new ArrayList<EventReminderDaysBO>());

                 //Here i need to add eventReminderDaysBOs to eventBOs
            }

            return eventBOs;
}
```

I can't add it normally like eventBOs.addAll(eventReminderDaysBOs)...How to add that..Please help me to find out the code..

This is my eventBO

```
private long eventId;

private long ringeeUserId;

private String text;

private String place;

private String eventDate;

private String startTime;

private String endTime;

private int isActive;

private int isDelete;

private List<EventReminderDaysBO> eventReminderDaysBOs;
```

I am using eventReminderDaysBOlist inside eventBO...

Comment: What's the link between `EventReminderDaysBO`  and `EventBO`? How do you get the `EventBO` from an `EventReminderDaysBO`?

Comment: Because `EventBO` and `EventReminderDaysBO` are two different classes

Comment: Is `EventReminderDaysBO` a subclass of `EventBO`?

Comment: I added the eventBo code

Comment: I am using eventReminderDaysBOList inside EventBO

Comment: you could add it to an `ArrayList<Object>`, but that would just be a clunky way to solve your problem. I would rather rethink the classdesign and might make a common interface for both classes or an inheritance from `eventBO` to `eventReminderDaysBOlist`.

Comment: @ Kevin Esche ..Is there any other way to add those object list